# Go back to different Activity in back stack in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, back-stack

Say I have an activity stack as such:
A -> B -> C -> D

I would like to create a new activity "E", and end up with a stack like this:
A -> B -> E

Basically, upon hitting the back button in activity D, I need to swap out activity C for activity E, and land on it.

Is this possible? Or should I be structuring the navigation differently somehow? Thanks!

Comment: you can add a slide animation(to look like moving to backstack) and `startActivity` according to your needs !! while going from C - > D  **FINISH** C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so while going from activity **C to D** `finish();` **C** activity.

At last at backPress method of Activity **D** call activity **E** and `finish();` Activity **D**