# Loading a different activity to the back stack to be loaded on back pr3ess

Tags: android, back-stack

This is my use case. I have to deep link into an activity that has a fragment associated with it. This deep link requires that we sign in to the app. This is my deep link flow

> Deep Link Handler Activity -> (Sign In) -> (Preference Activity).

If you were to navigate to the destination activity after logging in, which loads the main screen, then the navigation path would be

> (Main Activity) - > Activity A -> (Preference Activity)

The SignIn Activity calls the destination activity, and calls `finish()` thereby removing itself from the back stack. This is a legacy code, and can not be changed.

What I want to do is the following

After the destination activity is loaded after deeplink -> sign in, and if the user were to press the back button the first time, then I would like to load `Activity A` followed by `Home Screen` on another back button press.

Is there a way to achieve this? I have gone through the following tutorials

1. [Go back to different Activity in back stack in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126438/go-back-to-different-activity-in-back-stack-in-android)
2. [android activity back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869556/android-activity-back-stack) (This is the default behaviour).

My intent launch activity in the deep link handler activity.

```
Intent processorIntent = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
processorIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
processorIntent.putExtra(PARAM_PREFERENCE, preference);
processorIntent.putExtra(PARAM_FLOW, true);
startActivity(processorIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Main Activity) - > Activity A -> (Destination Activity)
```

You need to call `startActivity` when user press back button first time from the `Destination Activity` like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isFirstTime){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, A.class);
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_FLOW, true);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and do the same thing in `Activity A`